# Youtube displaying related videos even though rel=0 when using flash player, fine with HTML5 player

Tags: youtube

I've tried looking this up but I cannot find anything that quite explains my issue.

Basically, we have got YouTube videos embedded in our site, my bosses were asking why it was displaying related videos as we don't want to send people away from our site. 
I wasn't having this problem, but then I realized that I was using the HTML5 player, on turning it back to the flash player, I am now getting related videos showing at the end of it.

The URL has the rel=0 tag but yet the flash player is ignoring this, the HTML5 one is working fine, and most of our customers will not be using HTML5 player. 
Has been tested on several machines, opting in and out of the HTML5 YouTube and it is always the same result and being a business, it's quite important to the bosses, for me to get this fixed if there is anything I can do.

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this issue as well. It appears that if you are logged into Google.com (and thus Youtube.com) the &rel=0 is (sort of) respected as the full gamut of related videos is not displayed – However, what is displayed is a simpler version showing 2 videos directly related to videos you have looked at in the past. These videos do not appear to be related to the actual video itself, rather to your user account on Google.